# How do i Disable "Remember me on this Computer" checkbox from sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube5.1

I wanted to disable the checkbox for sonarqube login page, which says "Remember me on this computer"

Comment: Can anyone help me on this ASAP. I am admin of the Sonarqube console and it would be great if anyone can help with settings on the server. It is hosted on 64 bit Linux. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built it way to configure it. However, you can change the default value by removing "checked" from the HTML in the Ruby file under:

```
WEB-INF/app/views/sessions/_form.html.erb
```

Or you can comment out the checkbox/label entirely to hide it. This is a text file in the Sonar install directory so editable.

Note: this is the location in Sonar 5. Since it is an internal file, it could move around. You can rgrep to find it if you are on a different version.